# Groups with a unique lonely element

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

> Does there exist a finite group $G$ of order greater than two containing a unique element $g$ such that
> $$
> g\notin\langle x\rangle
> \hbox{ for all $x\in G\setminus\{g\}$ ?} 
> $$

<sub>Or we have another [fantastic property of the order-two group](https://mathoverflow.net/q/148925/24165)?</sub>

Clearly, such a group must be a 2-group, and the unique lonely element must be central and of order two.

Comment: Doesn't the Klein 4-group satisfy this?

Comment: No. It does not satisfy the uniqueness condition.  There are three lonely elements in the Klein group.

Comment: Restatement for a 2-group: find a 2-group of order $>2$ with a central element of order two $z$, such that every element $\neq z$ of order 2 is a square, but $z$ is not a square.

Comment: *`Restatement for a 2-group:... '* A group from the question **is necessarily** a 2-group.

Comment: I think @YCor's point was that their [revised condition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383115/groups-with-a-unique-lonely-element#comment974453_383115) can be satisfied for a non-2-group, and so doesn't imply your condition without an additional hypothesis.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that the nontrivial semidirect product of a cyclic group of order 4 $\langle x\rangle$ acting on another cyclic group of order 4 $\langle y\rangle$ is an example of such a group. The center of this group is $\langle x^2,y^2\rangle$ and $x^2y^2$ is not a square.

I came up with this trying to prove that no such group existed. In an example the center cannot be cyclic and then a minimal example had to be like this.

Comment: Very nice! What is your feeling: are there any chances to describe all examples?

Comment: I don't know, I felt that perhaps, but I have not pursued it any further.